# How do you kill the devil?

Tags: candy-box-2

Currently as soon as I reach him I get destroyed. I've tried ranged attacks, summoning, teleporting, and using my massive enchanted spoon, but to no avail. What is the tactic for beating the devil?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An easy way to kill him is to equip boots of introspection and the enchanted knight armor and to have the unicorn horn. And spam black demons

Answer (score 1):

Using the acid rain spell worked for me. It takes some time however, so make sure your spell cooldown is reasonably low and you have enough health & health potions.

Comment: I used black demons with boots of introspection. Worked well.