# How do i kill the bat that protects the devil

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm having trouble killing the bat and i've got the rocket boots the staff and crown and still cant even hit him

Comment: There's no real need to kill the bat, so this is basically a duplicate of [How do you kill the devil?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137159)

Comment: Summon demons.​

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i found is to use all your chochoclate bars to make those pains au chochlate (found in the big room) and then go to the wishing well and spend it all on magic 
you should then have 90% reduced cooldown times and in the room use your rocketboots and spam the "f" key to shoot fireball (if you can try and get the Big spoon and use your spamming ability to kill it quickly).

It worked for me and i had about 1000 HP